# Get the class name as tag from which the method is being called - Android Logging

Tags: java, android, kotlin, logging, stack-trace

I am trying to create a Logging class which only logs if the build is a debug build. This is my class

```
import me.entri.entrime.BuildConfig
import me.entri.entrime.utils.Constants

object Logger {

    private val TAG = Constants.LOGGING_TAG

    @JvmStatic
    fun d(message : Any?){
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG , message.toString())
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun d(message: Any? , e : Exception?){
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG , message.toString(), e)
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun e(message : Any?){
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.e(TAG , message.toString())
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun e(message: Any? , e : Exception?){
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.e(TAG , message.toString(), e)
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun w(message : Any?){
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.w(TAG , message.toString())
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun w(message: Any? , e : Exception?){
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.w(TAG , message.toString(), e)
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun v(message : Any?){
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.v(TAG , message.toString())
    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun v(message: Any? , e : Exception?){
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.v(TAG , message.toString(), e)
    }

}
```

As you can see currently I am hard coding the TAG with a string .
but instead I want to set the TAG as the class name from which this Log method has been called.

For eg :-
This is **splash.kt** class and if I call

```
try{
    
    val error = 4384/0    //arithmetic error for testing.

}catch(e : Exception){
    Logger.e("message")
}
```

Then my LogCat should show the class name as the TAG . ie Splash.kt

I tried to dissect Jake Wharton's timber library which has this functionality.

In that he seems to do something like this to get the class name from the stacktrace.

```
@get:JvmSynthetic 
    internal val explicitTag = ThreadLocal<String>()

    @get:JvmSynthetic 
    internal open val tag: String?
      get() {
        val tag = explicitTag.get()
        if (tag != null) {
          explicitTag.remove()
        }
        return tag
      }
```

And if the above tag is null then something like this.

```
override val tag: String?
      get() = super.tag ?: Throwable().stackTrace
```

I do not understand how both of these works , and even though I tried to use the same , I could not get the class name from which my Logger class was called.
Instead as a stacktrace class name all I got was my Logger class name itself.

So I wanted to know is there a any way to get the class name from which the my Logger class would be called.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get caller class name through couple of ways.

****1) Using StackWalker****

```
val className = StackWalker.getInstance(StackWalker.Option.RETAIN_CLASS_REFERENCE).callerClass
```

For using [StackWalker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.html) you need `Java 9` or `Greater`

**2) Using Thread StackTrace**

This will get the stacktrace of current thread.

```
val className =  Thread.currentThread().stackTrace[2].className
```

**3) By creating an exception and getting its stacktrace.**

```
val className = Exception().stackTrace[1].className
```